# Is it realistic for an android newbie to successfully complete a project in 30 days and submit it to ADC2?

Tags: java, android

Just for the disclaimer, I'm not trying to win the prize in Android Developer Challenge, but just want to participate.

I heard about the Android buzz lately and got interested in it. And today I stumbled upon a site talking about Android Developer Challenge 2. Luckily, the submission hasn't ended but unfortunately it starts tomorrow, August 1. Since this is a new opportunity I want to give it a try but I think I'm a little bit late.

I have configured the development platform and got some tutorials. I wanted to know if I could successfully develop a project within 30 days and submit it. Or is it really a big task which needs months of preparation. I just want to know if it is worth a try.

And for the record I know nothing about Androids except that it is an open source platform for application development on mobiles. I know Java but not competent, so may be need to touch up on that too.

It would be nice, if I get some real pointers on what I'm about to embark on. If it isn't possible I may need to pace down and enjoy other things in life too.

So is is possible to complete a small and decent app within 30 days or is it already late and if so are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The real answer: It Depends.

The size and your capacity of learning are very important. The smallest and simplest your app is, the more chances you have. The faster you learn, the more chances you have.

If you make it too complex, then you have no chance.

Note that being capable of making a decent app is different of being capable of making a great app. It's still possible, but it'll be a real challenge.

Comment: Suppose say it's a small game, something similar to tetris or say something little more complex like an to tweet from mobile.

Comment: Again, it depends. Some games are more complex than others(even some tetris are more complex than others), and the same applies to twitter from mobile. Have you ever made a tetris game/tweeter application before? Depending on these answers, the time for making a project will be variable. But I must admit Spencer's position of "why not just try?" may be a good one.

Answer (score 6):

My answer: Why not just try?

No matter what happens you'll get a lot of valuable experience. Working with a new technology, time management, project gauging,  working under pressure.

I really don't see a drawback to just giving it a shot.

Comment: Starting a side project with an actual deadline is a good idea. I might try doing this too.

Answer (score 3):

I had no prior Java experience when I did [my first](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/android/caltroid/) Android application in early 2008. There was very little documentation, and web searches mostly turned up nothing when you hit a snag. Nevertheless, I completed my first application in 15 days. So I would say you can easily code an application in 30 days nowadays if you have any prior software engineering experience. Of course, there is only so much you can do in 30 days, so don't aim for very complex application.

Comment: oh, great, what was your application. Can I see it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors that pose as a challenge for many android developers today which includes varying hardware features most especially. This can be rabbit hole if you want to touch on all places. Other challenges to expect are summaried at https://www.mytechgist.com/developers/most-common-difficulties-confronted-by-android-app-developers/